# Expiration date NET 4 Beta 1

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have 25 days left to use VS2010 Beta 1. Will I still be able to use an application made in this version after that or is there an expiration date of the framwork itself? And yes I am upgrading but for different reasons I need to use this application a couple of months more.
Anyone knows?

The application needs to run in Beta 1 IE I can not upgrade it until after a couple of months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes it works fine to run the application after the expiration date and even to run VS Beta if you just set the time back :) This has to be done before the expiration though!

Answer (score 1):

Applications built with the beta version of .NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010 will continue to work with the release versions.

Comment: You can also probably just recompile your app using the compiler and msbuild that's included in the framework. Or do you need to keep using the beta framework for test / certification reasons?